# Close off an unwanted window

Tags: framing, windows, brick, sheathing

I have a window that I'm looking to remove from the middle of the kitchen and replace with cabinetry. I will replace the opening with new framing and OSB for sheathing outside. My question is regarding house wraps, I'm thinking of using Tyvek in the area and taping it with the preexisting using sheathing tape. Lastly, cover with brick. Is this the correct method to do it? And, I'm thinking of doing this in early January, knowing the weather, is there a way to safely progress the project with the cold weather?

Comment: Sure. That's fine. What's your specific concern? What safety issues do you foresee?

Comment: Mortar for brick does not like cold temperatures, so you might have a problem if it is freezing cold out.

Comment: Give the local masons a call (note, that's "lower-case 'm'" masons, not "upper-case 'M'" Masons), and see if any of them would be willing to take on the job in January. You'll either get a "No", or they'll tell you the job will be more expensive because they'll have to erect a tent on the side of the house and heat it to keep the working temps inside warm enough to do the masonry work. You'll have to do the same. Go to your local big-box and look at the bags of mortar mix and see what the working temperature range is. You need it to be that warm, somehow.

Comment: This is not an instant job and doing it in January will probably mean having a hole in the wall open for some time(hopefully an hour or less), if nothing goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues: 1) moisture barrier, 2) vapor barrier, 3) wall insulation

1. Yes you need a moisture barrier and it needs to be installed correctly. Tyvek is fine, but I’d make sure it’s installed in “shingle fashion”. That is to say, make sure the top edge is tucked under the existing moisture barrier and the other 3 sides overlap the existing moisture barrier and all 4 sides well taped. (Be sure to check 6-8” back on the existing moisture barrier for cuts, splits, etc. because they could have covered them up when the window was installed.)
2. You need to match the existing vapor barrier or it will show a different “dryness” on the face of the brick wall. Vapor could escape out the wall and show a slight wetness on the face of the brick.
3. same with the insulation where the window was installed. I’ve seen where heat will travel through a wall at a different rate and show an area where the wall dries out quicker and it looks like a patch from the exterior.

Using the correct mortar and installing the bricks so they blend into the wall is more of an art than science. This may be the most difficult.